# Linear approximation in multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given the relations:
$$
\begin{align*}
&F_1(x,y,u,v) = ue^y +(y+1)e^{vx}+xy+1=0\\
&F_2(x,y,u,v) = x+y+xu+e^{y+v}-1=0
\end{align*}
$$
I am told I must find the linear approximation of $(u,v)$ in terms of $(x,y)$ near $(x,y,u,v) = (0,0,-2,0)$.

I understand that the linear approximation of $y=f(x)$ can be approximated by $f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$. However, from my understanding, the question seems to require that I separate the variables in to $(u,v)$ in terms of $(x,y)$ before application of the aforementioned relation. How would I go about doing that, if that even were to be the correct path of choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to adapt your notation to the multivariable case. Since your (*implicit*) function $(u,v)=f(x,y)$ is $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, the linear approximation is
$$f(x,y)\approx f(a,b) +J_f(a,b) \cdot (x-a,y-b)^\top$$
where $J_f$ is the jacobian matrix, i.e. the matrix of partial derivatives:
$$
J_f=\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} &  \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, the point is that partial derivatives can be obtained from the implicit function theorem without explicitly writing $(u,v)$ as a function of $(x,y)$. So, differentiating both equations with respect to $x$ gives:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}&=e^y \, \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ v\,(y+1)\,e^{vx} + x \,(y+1)\,e^{vx} \, \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} +y=0 \\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}&=1+u+x\,\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+
e^{y+v}\,\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} =0 
\end{align}
$$
and you can obtain both partial derivatives (observe that now the system is *linear*). Repeating the process with $y$ you obtain the other two. Finally, substituting for the point with the given values of $(u,v,x,y)$ gives the answer.

(By the way, as a reassuring exercise you should check that both equations hold for the given values of $(u,v,x,y)$. Otherwise the function $f$ is not defined by the equations at that point.)

Comment: The $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}$ partials were the parts I was having issue with. Thank you so much, this helped a lot!